# Authenticating Socket connection using JWT & Loopback 4

Tags: node.js, typescript, jwt, loopback4

I followed the following [example](https://github.com/raymondfeng/loopback4-example-websocket/) to build a chat app using LB4 and Socket.io, and now I need to secure the app the using JWT. How can I integrate JWT strategy that is mentioned in the following [reference](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authentication-Tutorial.html) as part my app architecture. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
@ws.connect()
@authenticate('jwt')
  connect(socket: Socket) {
    console.log('Client connected: %s', this.socket.id);
    socket.join('room 1');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I use [Interceptors](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Interceptors.html).

- create interceptor
- get the [Handeshake](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/socket.io/index.d.ts#L682) object
- authenticate it

Something like this:

1.In client side, create `socket` object by `Socket.io`

```
const socket = io(
    `YOUR_URL`,
    {
        "transports": ["websocket", "polling", "flashsocket"],
        "query": { "authorization": `Bearer ${token}` } // <= token in here
    }
);
```

2. create interceptor then use it in socket controller

```
export const SocketAuth = (): Interceptor => {
    return async (invocationCtx, next) => {
        const handshake: Handeshake = (invocationCtx.target as any).socket.handshake;
        // ...
    }
}
```

```js
@ws('/chat')
export class ChatController {

    @intercept(SocketAuth) // <= !!!!
    @ws.connect()
    async connect(socket: Socket) {
        // ...
    }

}
```